# WooCommerce: WooCommerce-table / order-details: how to split data into text and numbers

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I want to split the data of Shipping, payment and total in the product table, which is shown in the checkout , as well as int mails, send to the customers.

I want to split the classes into numbers and Text.

In case there is no number, the number 0 should be inserted

further more numbers should go amongst each other at the very right side, and the text as well, right behind the header shipping, payment and total.

-> The aim is to make the overview very clear:

Product xyz                            $10

Subtotal:                              $10
Shipping:         by mail              $5
Payment method:   cash                 $0
Total:            no Tax               $15

I tried to achieve it with the following code, but unfortunately it doesnt work properly, neither in the checkout table, nor in the email table.
Im not an expert, your help would be very aprreciated

```
add filter ('woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', function($total_rows, $tax_display)

{if (isset($total_rows[shipping]))
{$value=$total_rows['shipping']['value'];$value_split=explode('span',$value);

if (isset($value_split[0]))
{new_label_extra=$value_split[0];$new_value=wc_price($order->get_shipping_total());$total_rows['shipping']['label'].='<small>'.str._replace(':',",$new_label_extra).'</small>';$total_rows['shipping]['value']=$new_value;}}

if (isset($total_rows['payment_method'])
{$value=$total_rows['payment_method']['value'];$value_split=explode('<span',$value);

if (isset($value_split[0]))
{$new_label_extra=$value_split[0];$new_value=wc_price(0.0);$total_rows['payment_method']['label']-='<small>'.str_replace(':',",$new_label_extra).'<small>';$total_rows['payment_method']['value'=$new_value;}}

if (isset($total_rows['order_total']))
{$value=$total_rows['order_total]['value'];$value_split=explode('<small>',$value);

if (isset($value_split[1]))
{$new_label_extra="value_split[1];$new_value=wc_price($order->get_total();$total_rows['label'].='<small>'.str_replace(':',",$new_label_extra).'<small>';$total_rows['order_total']['value']=new_value;

if(class_exist('WGM_Template'))
{remove_filter('woocommerce_get_formated_order_total',array('WGM_Template','kur_review_order_item'),1,2);}}}return$total_rows;},100,3);
```

[screenshot of the aimed clear product_table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7uQv.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

-> In case someone else wants to split payment_method, shipping, method and total in text and numers

-> and re-arange them in the way, that numbers are placed at the very right and the text at the very left

you can use this code in your function.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', function( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {

if ( isset( $total_rows[ 'shipping' ] ) ) {
    $value = $total_rows[ 'shipping' ][ 'value' ];
    $value_split = explode( 'span', $value );
    if ( isset( $value_split[ 0 ] ) ) {
        $new_label_extra = $value_split[ 4 ];
        $new_value = wc_price( $order->get_shipping_total() );
        $new_label_extra2 = strip_tags($new_label_extra);
        $new_label_extra = str_replace(">",'',$new_label_extra2);
        $total_rows[ 'shipping' ][ 'label' ] .=  str_replace( ':', '', $new_label_extra );  
        $total_rows[ 'shipping' ][ 'value' ] = $new_value;
    }
}

if ( isset( $total_rows[ 'payment_method' ] ) ) {
    $value = $total_rows[ 'payment_method' ][ 'value' ];
    $value_split = explode( '<span', $value );
    if ( isset( $value_split[ 0 ] ) ) {
        $new_label_extra = $value_split[ 0 ];
        $new_value = wc_price( 0.0);
        $new_label_extra = ' '. $new_label_extra;
        $total_rows[ 'payment_method' ][ 'label' ] .=  str_replace( ':', '', $new_label_extra )  ;
        $total_rows[ 'payment_method' ][ 'value' ] = strip_tags($new_value);
    }
}

if ( isset( $total_rows[ 'order_total' ] ) ) {
    $value = $total_rows[ 'order_total' ][ 'value' ];
    $value_split = explode( '<small>', $value );
    if ( isset( $value_split[ 1 ] ) ) {
        $new_label_extra = $value_split[ 1 ];
        $new_value = wc_price( $order->get_total() );
        $new_label_extra2 = str_replace("</small>",'',$new_label_extra);
        $new_label_extra2 = ' ' . $new_label_extra2;
        $total_rows[ 'order_total' ][ 'label' ] .=  str_replace( ':', '', $new_label_extra2 );
        $total_rows[ 'order_total' ][ 'value' ] = $new_value;
                }
}

return $total_rows;}, 100, 3 );
```